# Does this prove my table work?

Tags: erlang

I think i create mnesia well because I add record in one node and i can see it in same table in the other node. Does this prove it work?

Comment: yes, it does my friend. It has worked ! Next Time though, paste your code to show what you have done so that we may fix other mistakes if any. well done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You covered distribution - good job ;)
The missing part is persistence. Make sure that your schema and tables are on disc (not in memory) -- of course only if it is desired.

Your friends are:

```
 mnesia:change_table_copy_type(schema, node(), disc_copies).
 mnesia:add_table_copy(SomeTableName, node(), disc_copies).
```

Usually it requires restart to apply changes.

You can consult mnesia:info() to see how your database looks like.